# Sources for Holding One's Left Hand in Right Hand During Prayer

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, hands-fingers

What are the earliest sources for the practice of holding one's left hand in one's right hand during prayer? (particular during the *Ammidah*).

The Talmud Shabbat (10a) notes a practice of holding one's hands during prayer, but does not specify the right hand being over the left.

> רבא שדי גלימיה ופכר ידיה ומצלי אמר כעבדא קמיה מריה

I always associated this with later kabbalists, but R. Avrahan ben HaRambam writes in *Sefer HaMaspik L'ovdey Hashem* (Halachic portion p. 65; translated from Arabic):

> ידיו שלובות ימינו על שמאלו כעבד נצב בשירות אדוניו, מנומס בעמידתו ירד וחרד

So my question is, is this the earliest known source or are there sources that can conclusively be proven to be earlier.

`Update`: currently the earliest source is the Mishneh Torah in the answer below. If someone posts an earlier source, the answer will be re-awarded.

---

Note: if I mistranslated the Gemara, or the Hebrew HaMaspik text, or if the Hebrew text seems to be a mistranslation of the Arabic, please correct.

Note: please only cite sources which *definitely* predate this. E.g. Mishneh Torah whose (rough) date of authorship is undisputed.

Comment: Whose translation from the Arabic is that?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's probably Nissim Dana's translation (of Part
Two, Volume Two of the book).

Comment: ויהיה לבו פנוי למעלה כאילו הוא עומד בשמים ומניח ידיו על לבו כפותין הימנית על השמאלית ועומד כעבד לפני רבו באימה ביראה ופחד ולא יניח ידיו על חלציו: mt tafillo 5:4 

רבא בר רב הונא רמי פוזמקי ומצלי אמר הכון לקראת וגו' רבא שדי גלימיה ופכר ידיה ומצלי אמר כעבדא קמיה מריה אמר רב אשי חזינא ליה לרב כהנא כי איכא צערא בעלמא שדי גלימיה ופכר ידיה ומצלי אמר כעבדא קמי מריה כי איכא שלמא . לביש ומתכסי ומתעטף ומצלי אמר הכון לקראת אלהיך ישראל
shabboth 10 a

pretty sure i saw in barokhoth somewhere about holding your hands to but i didnt look fully now maybe later

Comment: @DoubleAA it is indeed the Dana trans.

Comment: @mevaqesh Consider editing your post to clarify that?

Comment: @DoubleAA His is the only trans. indeed the only ed. of the halachic portion (TTBOMK). Thus, I reckoned that mentioning the name of the trans. was superfluous and added nothing.

Comment: @mevaqesh The one on wikipdeia https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A7_%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9D#/media/File:%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A7_%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9D.jpg seems to have been translated by a Yosef Dori

Comment: @DoubleAA at first glance it looks like the ethical, rather than the halachic portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [*Mishneh Torah*, *Hilkhot Tefilah* 5:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2205.htm) it says:

> תיקון הגוף כיצד:  כשהוא עומד בתפילה, צריך לכוון את רגליו זו בצד זו; ונותן עיניו למטה, כאילו הוא מביט לארץ; ויהיה ליבו פנוי למעלה, כאילו הוא עומד בשמיים; **ומניח ידיו על ליבו כפותין, הימנית על השמאלית**.  ועומד כעבד לפני רבו, באימה ויראה ופחד.  ולא יניח ידיו, על חלציו.‏

In  [Eliyahu Touger's translation](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920167/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Five.htm):

> The preparation of one's body: What is implied?
>
> When one stands in prayer, he should place his feet together side by side. He should set his eyes downwards as if he is looking at the ground, and his heart upwards as if he is standing in Heaven.
>
> **His hands should be resting on his heart, with the right hand clasped over the left hand**. He should stand like a servant before his master, in fear, awe, and dread. He should not rest his hand on his hips [during the Amidah].

Comment: This is interesting. Have you seen people do this? I rarely see this. AAMOF, sometimes I see people with their hands on a smart phone during Amidah!